# type II errors in Bartlett's test

Tags: statistics

Various statistical techniques are based on the assumption that two samples have the same variance and Bartlett's test is meant to check for that. Using R I made a few tests with randomly generated numbers. For example:

bartlett.test(list(rnorm(10,sd=1),rnorm(10,sd=2)))

will perform a Bartlett test on two vectors of 10 random numbers, where the random numbers are uniformly distributed with mean zero and standard deviation 1 and 2. When doing this with two vectors with the same standard deviation (and thus same variation) Bartlett's test will reliably confirm the null hypothesis of equal variances even with small sample sizes like 10, so there is a low risk of a type I error. However, if you do the test with different variances and a smallish sample size like 10 as in the example, Bartlett's test will confirm the null hypothesis around half the time (on repeated execution of the above line, depending on the particular random numbers it used). Although the variances differ by quite a lot, Bartlett's test will frequently not detect this with this sample size and make a type II error. If you increase the sample size, this effect disappears, as expected.

I read about Bartlett's test in multiple stats books and looked at the wikipedia entry but none of them seem to mention this high risk of a type II error for small samples. Is this known or did I miss something?

For practical applications, a type II error seem to be the bigger problem here as one will continue to work with the assumption of equal variances although it is false and thus reach statistical conclusions that are a lot stronger than they should be.